# RDP into linux machine creates new session every time

Tags: linux, remote-desktop

I'm trying to use RDP to remote into a linux machine (ubuntu) from a Windows host.
While it does work, it spawns a new desktop session (X session) every time and does not attach to the already existing desktop session. Should I startup the RDP server on the linux machine with specific args to have it attach to the current session?

EDIT: I just realized that I never used the X session before and was just having the default GNOME desktop session with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a brain-fart on my part. I never did have an X session up on my machine (I was using Ubuntu's default GNOME desktop environment). Of course when I spawn an X session, I can attach to it.